# Local PDF Not being Rendered in HTML on ubuntu

Tags: html, ubuntu, pdf, rendering, filepath

I have asked a question like this before and didn't receive and answer that worked. I've been working on this for too long.

This Code:

```
<ul style="list-style-type:circle">
    <li><iframe src="file:///home\name\Desktop\name.pdf"></iframe></li>
```

Is not working. I have dragged and dropped my PDF into my browser and know for a fact this is the path.

I have also tried `<embed>` and `<a href`

I am seeing just a blank white box where the PDF should be displayed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the code? perhaps you have something else that breaks it. Your above code should work (Just remember to add the closing `<ul>` tag.

Comment: Actually, if you see the blank box, you're code should be good. The issue on the path.

Comment: When you say that you see a blank box, does it say "It may have been moved or deleted" ?

Comment: right, this is what's confusing me! however, I have dragged the pdf into my browser and come up with this.

Comment: Nope, says nothing!

Comment: Which browser are you using? (Just want to make sure if the issue is on the path or on the code)

Comment: Chrome! I have even tried using <a href and nothing is coming up. Only thing showing there is that URL is not found.

Comment: anything? Still confused!

Comment: I'm thinking... First confirm the following, which OS are you  using? Can you find a PDF URL and see if that works?

Comment: I am using ubuntu

Comment: I think that when I am runnin on 127.0.01:5000, this becomes 127.0.0.1:5000/file///home/etc

Comment: Try to reference it with out the "file" just <a href="/home\name\Desktop\name.pdf">Link here</a>

Comment: nope. URL not found! I think its the same issue!

Comment: Hey! still lost on this...

Comment: I wish I can help, I added the tags ubuntu and filepath so people with knowledge in this can get to this question, It will be published upon review. You didn't answer the following: Can you find a PDF online and link that URL and see if that works?

Comment: well the PDF is private lol

Comment: Not your PDF, any PDF, just to confirm that the path is the issue here.

Comment: a random PDF path works....